# is it possible to query documents from firebase to flutter depending on dateTime Value?

Tags: firebase, flutter

im trying to query documents from my firestore to my flutter application in 2 ways , first one is getting all documents when the "translator" field in my "Patients" collection is = '$currentUser' like the following and its working fine:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Patients')
        .where('translator', isEqualTo: _auth.currentUser!.displayName)
        .snapshots()
```

next thing i want to do is querying data according to the "arrival date" field which is DateTime Formatted to String as shown

[image: image link]

how can i get all documents where the current DateTime is before the arrival date , something like this

```
 FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('Patients')
            .where('arrivalDate' , '????': arrivalDate.isBefore(DateTime.now())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you'll just need to format the date into the same format that you have in your documents.

Something like this:

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
...
String formattedDate = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(now);

FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('Patients')
            .where('arrivalDate' , isLessThan: formattedDate)
```

Comment: oh is it that easy ? :) so im not obligated to use one of the given parameters (  isEqualTo
  isNull
  isGreaterThan
  arrayContainsAny etc...) ? and i can use '<='

Comment: or i have to use isGreaterThanOrEqualTo instead of '<=' ?

Comment: Ah right, good catch. I was too focused on the date format, so forgot the value syntax on Flutter. On Flutter it's indeed `isLessThan` (since you wanted before the date). I updated in my answer too.

Comment: Also: it seems your `arrivalDate` is nested under a `travelInfo` field in which case it'd be: `.where('travelInfo.arrivalDate' , isLessThan: formattedDate)`

Comment: thanks for your help , i just tried your solution it worked but its getting the documents where the date isBefore formatted date and when arrival date = "" (which is the initial value for the field) , any idea about why this is happening ? i dont need the to fetch the documents where arrival date = ""

Comment: thanks again for your help and time <3 i got my answer and my problem solved